# Select dropdown does not work in iframe within chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, drop-down-menu, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension. All of the UI is served from our website and wrapped in an `<iframe>` within the extension (*example.com/extension*). The UI features a `<select>` dropdown. The `<select>` functions as it should when I visit *example.com/extension* in the browser, but when I open the page via the extension, the `<select>` does not expand to show the options within it.

I can click on the `<select>` to give it focus. I DO know that the dropdown is being populated because I can click on the `<select>` and type alphanumeric characters to choose options within the `<select>`. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: [Here's an example of the issue](https://github.com/LukeStanbery89/iframe-extension).

Edit: It may be a Chrome bug. I [reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=726743) it to Chromium.org.

Comment: Is there any way to see a live example? So far it sounds like a [bug](https://crbug.com)

Comment: Clone [this repository](https://github.com/LukeStanbery89/iframe-extension) and load it up in Chrome. It's not linked to my site, but the same issue occurs.

Comment: Yep, definitely looks like a bug. Report it.

Comment: you could post the link of the bug so future readers will be able to follow the thread.

Comment: I [reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=726743) it to Chromium.org. Thanks for the input.